Godot 4 Static Storage Handling
I have a project that will have a significant amount of item/entity data. Imagine something like a survival game that will have items being dropped that can be used in recipes and building. There will be some additional logic associated with each item, but this is the gist of it.
I've read some people suggest databases like SQLite, but some people suggest this may be a bit overkill.
In my opinion a database would be the obvious choice for structured relational data, but it seems most examples I see use their own implementation based on JSON files or Resources.
I'm not looking for a silver bullet or anything, but would like to understand if there is any "big no no" I'm missing or a pro/con that could tip the scales on database vs tailor-made files for local static data like item metadata, recipes, drop probability, health, durability, and so on?
Besides, one advantage I see in already having a DB is that it can also be used for some dynamic data as well, or am I missing something performance wise?

What advantage does a SQL database have over the built in tools that Godot provides: The scene tree, JSON serialization and support for binary formats?
To say that another way, unless you have a very specialized use case, most likely you ain't gonna need a SQL database.

The main advantage I see in using a DB is better data management. It seems to me that managing 100 or more items' metadata in a JSON file may get easily unmanageable.

I would choose Godot Scenes over JSON in most cases. The Godot Scene tree is a data store ("database" typically implies ACID - which Godot isn't). Your question is effectively saying I want to replace MongoDB with PostgreSQL - there might be a valid reason for doing that, but you are going to need to get very specific about exactly what type of "data management" operation you need to do, i.e. identify an operation that Godot scene tree does so poorly that it's worth the effort of ripping it out and replacing it with something else.

Ok. I may need to think about this a bit further, but most likely the design I had in mind would still contain the Godot scenes, the main difference is things like a tree scene will not contain its drops, nor the wood scene will "know" about the tree. Instead both will be connected through a many to many relationship with some additional metadata like drop rate and quantity. The same for wood usages. a wall will be a object defined in godot, but needing X wood to be built, plus X tool and X duration will be set in a table loaded in the beginning of the game.

TLDR: Use OOP and let Godot handle data storage. You focus on your game.
Everything I've read since Godot 4 was released suggests that JSON serialization is no longer the way to go, especially for saving data. I've used SQLite before professionally and I love it for quick development. SQLite is great for a number of reasons. It's easy to setup compared to other DBs. It requires no networking. It is limited because of the way it stores files, in that large amounts of data will slow down its performance, but I doubt you'll be putting enough data in to matter.
If you are familiar with SQL, and like to think in terms of normalized databases, this could be a good way for you to go, but unless there's a strong knowledge component on your part, I would recommend against it.
Instead, I would recommend you let Godot handle the data, and you think it OOP concepts. I have a couple of generic scripts on my objects that handle a lot of things. For example, anything on the ground has this script attached to it:
extends Node3D

class_name Pickup

signal death(item_name: String)

@export var item_name: String
## The [PackedScene] to pass to the player character to add to inventory.
## [b]NOTE:[/b] [i]If this is left empty, gold will be added to the player's
## using the number or range from the amount field. This is a good way to
## allow the conversion of items to gold without requiring an intermediary.[/i]
@export var item: PackedScene
## The amount of the item to inventory as an [Array] of [int]s.
## If only 1 value is supplied, that amount will be added.
## If 2 values are supplied, it will use the first number as the minimum
## amount and the second number as the maximum amount and return a random value
## between the two (inclusive).
## If 3 or more values are supplied, it will randomly select one of the options
## from the list and send that amount.
## Defaults to giving the player one of the item.
@export var amount: Array[int] = [1]
## The sound to play when the item is picked up as an [Array] of [AudioStream]s.
## If no tracks are supplied, no sound is played.
## If only 1 track is supplied, that sound always plays.
## If 2 or more values are supplied, it will randomly select one of the options
## from the list and send that sound file.
## [b]NOTE:[/b] [i]You always want to use .WAV files for sound effects when you can.[/i]
@export var sound_on_pickup: Array[AudioStream]

func _ready() -> void:
    $PickupTrigger.body_entered.connect(_on_pickup_trigger_body_entered)
    add_to_group("pickup")


func _on_pickup_trigger_body_entered(body):
    #print("Pickup Collision")
    if body.has_method("pickup_item"):
        body.pickup_item(item, _get_amount(), _get_audio_file())
        death.emit(item_name)
        queue_free()


func _get_amount():
    var choices = amount.size()
    match choices:
        1:
            return amount[0]
        2:
            var rng = RandomNumberGenerator.new()
            return rng.randi_range(amount[0], amount[1])
        _:
            return amount.pick_random()


func _get_audio_file():
    if sound_on_pickup.is_empty():
        return
    return sound_on_pickup.pick_random()

For every item in the game that's on the ground, I just apply this script and drag and drop the pickup sound, and what possible things can be picked up. My game gives random loot, but you could do something like this for specific loot, or even populate it at runtime with equipped items if you wanted.
If I had more complex items than gold and powerups, I would do the same with items. For example I would attach a script to all weapons that stored all the possible combinations as exported variables, and then I would set them, and store the items in my game.
If I wanted to randomly generate various properties onto items, I would store them in exported array variables. That way, I can edit it all in the Godot editor, and I let Godot worry about storage.
Based on what you're suggesting, with crafting items, I would also take this approach. Then all you have to do is store your recipe logic somewhere else. I can think of two ways to do this. First, is add an export variable:
@export var crafting_resource_name: String

Then, if the variable is set, it can be used as a crafting resource in recipes, and otherwise it is skipped over.
The second way would be to add Node groups for each resource type and look for those. This has the advantage of making your object files slightly smaller, but has the disadvantage that you have to look at another tab for crafting resources.

The key point behind your question was that you didn't want to manage metadata in JSON files. Out of the box Godot gives you two (related) alternatives:

Create objects in a supported scripting language (GDScript or C#).
Edit object metadata in the GUI.

These options are related because you can add your custom classes to the Scene tree which then exposes each of the properties in the GUI to be edited - the values are stored with the scene and re-instantiated when the scene is loaded.
In the comments you mentioned that you wanted to decouple the generic attributes of items from the specific instances (spawn locations) in a map. To do this you need to use two scenes. One scene contains the map (with spawn locations) the other is just a storage container containing all the attributes. When an item is spawned/dropped you will need code to lookup the attributes from the "metadata" scene and generate an appropriate object in the level scene. However by structuring your project this way you can edit both the map and the metadata in the GUI.
Depending how much work you want to put into your metadata scene, you can utilize things like color/asset pickers, set valid ranges for properties (use sliders to set values) and have the values reflect inside the editor (without needing to launch the game). The main advantage of this approach is that non-programmers can contribute changes (they don't need to write code to do so). If your entire team is programmers a simple script to build the whole item catalogue may be sufficient.
TL;DR - I think you are going to have a lot of work rebuilding the functionality described above, if you want to integrate a different data store.
